# realm. remove objects from ListBase

Tags: swift, realm

I have different realm models. They have List properties. I want to make universal way for removing objects from List properties. So I did the following:

```
if let list = self[property.name] as? ListBase {
    list._rlmArray.removeAllObjects()
}
```

but this just clear list property, without deleting objects from realm. The only way I've found is:

```
if let list = self[property.name] as? ListBase {

    while list.count > 0 {
        let object = list._rlmArray.firstObject()
        let any = object as Any

        if let theObject = any as? Object {
            realm.delete(theObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Code above works and doesn't generate any warning. But it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dynamicList(_ propertyName: String)` to retrieve `List` property by name instead subscript.

```
if property.type == .array {
    try! realm?.write {
        realm?.delete(dynamicList(property.name))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect.

Comment: Use `RLMSwiftCollectionBase` instead of `ListBase`.

Answer (score 0):

When Realm removed ListBase the following solution worked for me.
Use `RLMSwiftCollectionBase` instead of `ListBase`.

Original Source:
https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream/pull/256#issuecomment-1034336992